# ASP.NET MVC - Pass JQuery variables to Razor?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have table data that show list of taxi position. 
Each taxi had their own places near its position.

I want to show the list of places through a popup.
here's the code when i call the popup modal:

```
<a href="#assign" data-id="@item.idMobil" data-toggle="modal" class="open-detailIncident"> @item.idMobil </a>
```

here's the javascript code to get the taxi data selected :

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".open-detailIncident", function () {
        var idMobil = $(this).data('id');
        $(".modal-body #idMobil").val(idMobil);
    });
</script>
```

here's the popup view :

```
<div id="assign" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="assign" aria-hidden="true">

        @{
            var dictionary = ViewBag.ListTempat as Dictionary<string, List<Place>>;

            foreach (var tempat in dictionary[idMobil])
            {
                @tempat.Nama_Tempat
            }

        }
</div>
```

**here's the error i got :**
[image]

**Edited : 
Can you help me how to pass the idMobil from jQuery to Razor ?**

Comment: `idMobil` is a javascript variable and you are using it in razor syntax. You can't mix javascript and C#.

Comment: And suppose `idMobil` is a C# variable. So you are using it in `foreach` in `dictionary`. First thing to note that if dictionary does not contain key related to idMobile then it is going to throw exception and the other thing is `dictionary[idMobil]` will return only one value so there is not sense to use `foreach`.

Comment: @mmushtaq i'm new to c# dev that's why i'm asking this question thankyou for your explanation. dictionary[idMobil] will return only one value yes it is List<Place> and i want to iterate through the list. it won't throw exception because i handled it on the controller before sending it to view.

Comment: The convention should be that Razor initially populates the view, and then you can use Javascript/JQuery to dynamically interact with that page. Think in those terms. If data doesn't exist at page load then Razor will not be able to build it later. You can always use JQuery to dynamically build an html tag string and then append it to the modal with your data. You can also store model data in a hidden input in a JSON encoded string if you want to use view model data in JS code, however that breaks the convention of separation of elements even though it will work.

Comment: Common method to pass JS variable into Razor (partial) view is using AJAX call which calls action method rendering (partial) view inside modal popup. In this case, you can send `idMobil` as JSON string to an action method which iterating through `ListTempat` and returning result as partial view.